# .htaccess is affecting wrong site

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

i'm hosting multiple domains on an Ubunbu/Apache2 setup using virtual domains.

my file structure looks like this

```
 - var
 - - www
 - - - html(can be viewed by visiting my public ip)
 - - - - .htaccess
 - - - domain1.com
 - - - - html(can be viewed by visiting domain1.com)
 - - - - - .htaccess
 - - - domain2.com
 - - - - html(can be viewed by visiting domain2.com)
 - - - - - .htaccess
 - - - domain3.us
 - - - - html(can be viewed by visiting domain3.com)
 - - - - - .htaccess
 - - - domain4.com
 - - - - .htaccess
 - - - - html(can be viewed by visiting domain4.us)
```

for some reason, domain4.com's .htaccess file is only affecting the html folder directly inside the www, and not domain4.com's html folder like it should be. none of the other .htaccess files are working completely right.

/var/www/html's .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule wp-login.php http://domain3.com/404e.php [R=301]
RewriteRule xmlrpc.php http://domain3.com/404e.php [R=301]
```

domain1.com's .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule wp-login.php http://domain1.com/404e.php [R=301]
RewriteRule xmlrpc.php http://domain1.com/404e.php [R=301]
```

domain2.com's .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule wp-login.php http://domain2.com/404e.php [R=301]
RewriteRule xmlrpc.php http://domain2.com/404e.php [R=301]
```

domain3.us has no .htaccess file.

domain4.com's .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]



RewriteRule wp-login.php http://domain4.com/404e.php [R=301]
RewriteRule xmlrpc.php http://domain4.com/404e.php [R=301]
RewriteRule index.html http://domain4.com/index.php [R=301]
```

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

domain1.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
    ServerAdmin an_email_addy@yahoo.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1.com/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined       
    <Directory /var/www/domain1.com/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

domain2.com.conf

```
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com
    ServerAdmin anemail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
            <Directory /var/www/domain2.com/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

domain3.us.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>      

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain3.us/html
    ServerName www.domain3.us
    ServerAlias domain3.us        
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/domain3.us/html/ >
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

domain4.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain4.com
    ServerAlias www.domain4.com
    ServerAdmin anemail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain4.com/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/domain4.com/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

i've been trying to use my strongest google-fu to figure this out for days now and can't figure out why domain4.com's .ht is affecting /var/www/html/ when it has its own.... or why it would be affecting any folder UP the tree.
if you need me to show any additional info i will just ask.

all i'm trying to do is get it to remove the extensions on pages.

the 404e page is because i've noticed a lot of random ip's trying to get to those two files specifically to see if i'm running wordpress, i know that most likely no one will ever see it, but it was a fun little project for me, its a page that refreshes itself 5 times a second and on each refresh the background color and font size change, and the font color changes based on the contrast of the background color, so its almost always visible. but anyways about why i mention the 404e is because each one of those for each site works. its just any other commands i try to add to the .htaccess file do nothing.

Comment: Are you certain it's not an issue with the vhost config file? You're correct AFAIK, `.htaccess` files should work in the current directory.

Comment: i can post that info as well. i'll edit the original post

Comment: i have updated the original post, i hope that i added the right information.

Comment: @Toby is there anything in my vhosts stuff that looks out of wack?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not seeing anything that might cause this issue. If this were me, I would start from scratch, and setup one domain, verify that everything is working, then setup the next and verify that, etc. Also, I have no idea what the recommended path is, but I personally wouldn't maintain the `/var/www` once I had begun using vhosts - I don't believe it's causing the problem, but it would be easier to test and verify without.